# When using vue.js 2.0, how do you pass an array index to a method inside of a v-on:click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying out vue 2.0 for the first time today. You can see my first attempt at using vue below. I am trying to pass the index of the array into a method. I have tried lots of different ways of doing this but none have been successful. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks!

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="content_block" v-for="(entry, index) in entries" :key="entry.title">
        <ul>
            <li>title: {{entry.title}}</li>
            <li>names: {{entry.names}}</li>
            <li>index: {{index}}</li>
            <button v-on:click="addName('{{index}}','susan')">Susan</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var the_data = [{"title":"developer","names":["john","bob"]},{"title":"designer","names":[]}];

    var vm = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: {
            entries: the_data
        },
        methods: {
            addName: function(index, the_name){
                console.log(index + " : " + the_name);
                            this.data.entries[index].names.push(the_name);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `addName(index, 'susan')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use interpolation inside attribute values.

Please, try:

```
<button v-on:click="addName(index, 'susan')">Susan</button>
```

You can use the shorthand `@` for `v-on`:

```
<button @click="addName(index, 'susan')">Susan</button>
```